# Need help in understanding the Capsicum capability mode and its effect on getpass()

Tags: c, freebsd

I am experimenting with the Capsicum framework on FreeBSD. I am trying to learn how to use its sandboxing capabilities. While experimenting, I discovered that if I enter capability mode with cap_enter() prior to calling getpass(), the passphrase is echoed to the terminal as you're typing. I clearly don't want that, but the rest of the program still runs as expected with no errors. If we call cap_enter() after getpass(), it behaves normally and the rest of the program executes as expected.

The first two questions that occurred to me are:

- What causes this behavior?
- Can I use cap_enter() or another Capsicum function that can be used in such a way as to allow me to enter capability mode *before* calling getpass() and having it behave normally? How is this done?

[This article from 2012 by David Chisnall](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1924012) maybe give a hint on the second page in the section "File Descriptors as Capabilities".

As I say, I'm working on FreeBSD; 14.0-RELEASE-p4. Here is a simple program that demonstrates the issue with getpass(). My initial expectation was that getpass() would behave normally. I'd like to understand why it doesn't inside capability mode, and how to fix it so I can use getpass() inside capability mode with no echo.

```c
//cap_test.c

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/capsicum.h>

#include "test.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Entering capability mode  here causes getpass()
    // to echo the passphrase.
    //cap_enter();
  
    char* pwd = getpass("Passphrase: ");
    
    // By making the call here, the passphrase is
    // not echoed.
    cap_enter();

    // The SHA256() function takes a char* as input and returns
    // an unsigned char pointer.
    uchar* key =  SHA256(pwd);
    memset(pwd, 0, sizeof(pwd)*sizeof(pwd[0])); // added in edit
    
    // Echo 32 hash bytes
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
        printf("%x ", key[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Zero-out key memory location to check that it works.                                          
    memset(key, 0, 32*sizeof(key[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

The simple header file gives us a typedef and function prototype:

```c
typedef unsigned char uchar;
extern unsigned char* SHA256(char*);
```

Comment: After reading the article, it looks to me as if you will need to write your own analogue of `readpassphrase()` using the Capsicum facilities to allow you to open `/dev/tty`.  You'll have to decide what to do if the program has no controlling terminal.  However, the article is from 2012; a lot may have changed/expanded in the world of Capsicum in the last decade, so read the manuals to see what options there are.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, you've actually helped to point me in the right direction. FWIW, the man page for `getpass(3)` on FBSD does not warn that it's obsolete or depricated. (Perhaps it should!)

Comment: I would have expected that if getpass() or readpassphrase() couldn't access /dev/tty once inside the Capsicum sandbox, they would just fail. Not the case. Reading the man page for both more _carefully_ than I did at first, I see that if /dev/tty is not accessable, they both echo the input to stderr. So, that partially answers one of my questions! :-) Also, it looks like crypt(3) might be a better option in general. It remains to be seen what sort of hoops need to be jumped through. If not, I think I can work with readpassphrase(3). Now I'm off to get this working. Thank you again.

Comment: I've found a recent and informative article by Jake Freeland [here](https://www.cdaemon.com/posts/capsicum). Thanks @jonathan-leffler for your earlier comments.

Comment: An answer would be helpful. Thanks @jonathan-leffler! I'm making small-step progress; doing a lot of reading of man pages and an AsiaBSDcon article on Capsicum by Mariusz Zaborski.

Comment: Google found a couple of presentation videos by Marius Zaborski (search term "capsicum asiabsdcon zaborski").  It also tried to make 'bacon' out of the conference name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the [`getpass(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html) function is clearly marked: "This function is obsolete.  Do not use it." Now might be a good time to heed that advice.  See also the NOTES section and the commentary about using [`readpassphrase()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readpassphrase) from libbsd.

After reading the article you reference in the question, it looks to me as if you will need to write your own analogue of `readpassphrase()` using the Capsicum facilities to allow you to open `/dev/tty`.  You'll have to decide what to do if the program has no controlling terminal.  However, the article is from 2012; a lot may have changed/expanded in the world of Capsicum in the last decade, so read the manuals to see what options there are.

It would be worth looking for more recent material on Capsicum.  Wikipedia on [Capsicum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_(Unix)) is an obvious place to look, as is the manual page for [`capsicum(4)`](https://man.freebsd.org/capsicum(4)) and the FreeBSD Wiki on [Capsicum](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Capsicum) — no doubt, you're already aware of these.  A Google search also shows links to Cambridge University Computer Laboratory, which initiated the work on [Capsicum](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/capsicum/freebsd.html).

Comment: I feel the need to reiterate the comment that `getpass(3)` is **not obsolete** under FreeBSD. To be clear for those who read this and do not know--FreeBSD is not Linux. But the `getpass` difference might make an interesting question for SO since it appears to be an implementation problem with gnu C while FreeBSD uses clang

Comment: @Rob: I think that the GNU C Library (which is used on Linux) declares `getpass()` obsolete because it doesn't provide good controls over the length of the password that can be entered, etc.  By contrast, the BSD `readpassphrase()` function does provide such controls — take a bow, BSD!  Declaring `getpass()` obsolete is also a recommendation to use a better function.  The `getpass()` function has not yet been removed from glibc; it may 'never' be removed.  But it is not the recommended tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you @rob for the insight on `getpass()` FreeBSD. I was wondering why it was not declared obsolete in FBSD, while it is in the other OS. I do have to agree with @jonathan-leffler that `readpassphrase()` is a better tool, based on my limited experimenting with both. (And reading the man pages!)

Comment: Probably not news to either of you, but the other OS does provide readpassphrase(). On Debian-based systems one needs the `libbsd0` and `libbsd-dev` packages installed; it's not included in the base system as in FreeBSD and OpenBSD.  Funny though, it's not included by default on NetBSD. In my 'real' program that was using `getpass()` and now uses `readpassphrase()`, I use a `#ifdef` block to `#include <bsd/readpassphrase.h>` for a Linux build.

Answer (score 0):

In his paper [Capsicum and Casper - a fairy tale about solving security problems](https://oshogbo.vexillium.org/pdf/AsiaBSDcon2016.pdf), Mariusz Zaborsk gives an example of how to give rights to `stdin` and `stdout` as used in the file utility `uniq(1)` from FreeBSD. Thank you, [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), for your help in getting me going in the right direction.

This answers my question:

```c
caprights_t rights;
. . .
ifp = stdin;
ifn = "stdin";
ofp = stdout;

if (argc > 0 && strcmp(argv[0], "−") != 0)
    ifp = file(ifn = argv[0], "r");
cap_rights_init(&rights, CAP_FSTAT, CAP_READ);

if (cap_rights_limit(fileno(ifp), &rights) < 0 && errno != ENOSYS)
    err(1, "unable to limit rights for %s", ifn);
cap_rights_init(&rights, CAP_FSTAT, CAP_WRITE);

if (argc > 1)
    ofp = file(argv[1], "w");
else
    cap_rights_set(&rights, CAP_IOCTL);
if (cap_rights_limit(fileno(ofp), &rights) < 0 && errno != ENOSYS) {
    err(1 , "unable to limit rightsfor %s", argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdout");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jonathan-leffler for the edit; I meant to link Mariusz Zaborsk's paper, but was distracted at the time. Glad you put it in there.